# Re-labeling columns in R

Tags: r

I need to replace number values with something that makes more sense to the reader.

Value “-0.95197” represents “18-24” age group in the given table.

What would be the best way to go about this for all columns?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear. Are you trying to rename the header of each column in a data.frame?  If so, try this, where `df` is the name of your data.frame.  You need one piece of text for each column.

```
names(df) <- c("your", "header", "names", "go", "here")
```

If this is not what you want, then you need to provide more info.